# VSCode Powershell Auto Correct Aliases Parameter not working as intended

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I am having a question about using PowerShell with Visual Studio Code.
For some reason it does not want to remember the settings of:
Code Formatting: Auto Correct Aliases & Use Correct Casing
These are both switched off and still it marks the usage of Aliases and Incorrect Cmdlet Names
But when I click one of these parameters on and off it works for both of them for a while again. Meaning that when I uncheck Auto Correct Aliases within the config file and without touching (checking/unchecking) the other parameter 'Use Correct Casing' it also unmarks 'Use Correct Casing' syntax errors within the ps doc and visa versa... 
 Is this maybe a config file mix-up in between account profiles ??

Setting this in the settings.json seem to have no effect, it just seems to wanna mark these for some reason again, any other parameter within this config file seem to work as intended.
Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved it (not sure if it was the actual solution) by reinstalling code and using the user setup instead of the admin setup , they also ask to use/install the user version. It might have been a cross profile issue, something that got mixed up in between config files or an issue with the 'PSScriptAnalyzerSettings.psd' file. But it is working now , it doesn't complain about the usage of aliases and incorrect cmdlet names anymore.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, this setting is not working as intended. I tried it on multiple computers and versions and it still wouldn't work. I reported it as an issue on Github:
https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/2608

**Alternative I use**

I started using the shortcut `Shift + Alt + E`. This worked perfectly for me and every once in a while I press these keys and all my aliases are expanded. Alternatively you can press `f1` and then type `Expand Alias` and press `Enter`.

~ Nicicalu